# Parent View Controller doesn't rotate while Child View Controller is presented

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent view controller that supports all four orientations. It presents a child view controller, and if the device is rotated while the child view controller is presented, and then you dismiss the child, the parent view controller is not rotated correctly. Here is the code I use for rotation in the parent view controller:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    newestIssueCoverImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 20, 688, 865);
    shadow.frame = CGRectMake(40, 20, 688, 865);
    recordView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 916);
    classifiedsWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 916);

} else {

    newestIssueCoverImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(269, 20, 486, 613);
    shadow.frame = CGRectMake(269, 20, 486, 613);
    recordView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024, 660);
    classifiedsWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024, 660);

}
```

The parent looks at though this code wasn't used and I just rotated the device. How do I call this code and ensure that the parent view controller is rotated correctly when the user is currently looking at the child? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Apple's docs:

> If a view controller is not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews method is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the device orientation.

I added a BOOL to track when it is not the top viewController, then:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    if (notTopController) {

        [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] duration:0];
        [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] duration:0];

       notTopController = NO;

}
```

Works good for me so far.

Comment: I had to adapt this for my situation (I had a container view controller which wasn't getting sized correctly) but the basic logic here was sound.

Answer (score 2):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `RotateToInterfaceOrientation` and  only get called on the current/visible view controller, not the views "behind" it on the stack. In your case, when the child is visible, it is being called on the child but not on the parent.

If there has been a rotate event, when you dismiss the child view controller (assuming you a using a NavigationController), `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` will be called on the parent (but **not** `will/didRotate`). If you want to see for yourself, throw some `NSLog()` statements in all these methods.

Knowing all that, a quick fix would be to throw your resize code into the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the explanation. I will try that. Btw, I looked at your profile and your Trakr app is really cool.

Comment: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is now deprecated. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621459-shouldautorotatetointerfaceorien

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that **both** parent and child view controllers supports rotation. **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:**